# Render issues while using animation nodes and command line rendering

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a procedural animation that basically breaks down into 2 components. 1 is a rotating focal point object (with some vector wiggle) and the other is a grid of cubes being wiggled randomly while also being scaled by audio input.

Now, in my recent exposure to animation nodes I found recommendations on removing crashes. One of which is running the following script within blender.

```
import bpy

start_frame = <start>
end_frame = <end>
fps = 30
path = 'D:\\<path>'

for frame in range(start_frame, end_frame + 1):
    bpy.context.scene.render.fps = fps
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath= path + '\\%04d.png' % frame
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Now this works fine and all of the animation nodes execute properly and render the frames without issues.

However, I went to try and make a batch script so that I could run this with just checking the terminal output with the following.

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,2880) do ( 
   "<blender_path>" -b project.blend -o "<frame_path>\####" -f %%a 
)
```

When I run it this way, the grids drivers work properly and the animation renders as expected. But my focal point (In this case the head) does not get driven, and I cant figure out why that portion of the animation nodes is not executing (Its really just an Euler rotation being driven by frame position.)

Any ideas why it might execute differently with the bpy script vs cmd line calls? Im probably not understanding the difference between the scripts commands vs what runs when you call a project from command line.

Scene for reference -
[image: Grid and Focal Scene]

Comment: Animation nodes can be buggy when rendering objects with animated values. I suggest baking to keyframes beforehand. There is a handy operator in the AN properties in the N panel to do it

Comment: Ah yea, I should have mentioned that. Baking to keyframes has worked for me before but with the deforming mesh and the many objects with constant transforms I was running into the baking process crashing (made it to about half way through until it just locked up and crashed)